# Show HTML text if window width is too small with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to hide my HTML `table` and show the following text: `"There's not enough space to show table."`, if the window width is smaller than 500px. Anybody know how to do that?

**HTML:**

```
<section>
  <h2>Status</h2>
  <table class="MyClass">
    <caption>Random text</caption>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td> 
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td> 
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
 .MyClass { 
    display:none;
  }
//SHOW TEXT
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer with JS version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/154/

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    section table {
        display: none;
    }    

    section:after {
        content: "There is not enough space to show table";
    } 
}
```

Or you can do this with JS https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/155/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 500) {
       $('.MyClass').css('display', 'none');
       $('.info').css('display', 'block');          
    } else {
      $('.MyClass').css('display', 'block');
       $('.info').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```